# [tomcat error]Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm experiencing this kind of exception while starting up the project, can someone help me about this problem? I don't know if it's the tomcat deploy error or the code error.It seemed to connect successfully and then failed.I try to redeploy project again and again,but it still does't work.The log is below:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59454', transport: 'socket'
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.818 警告 [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.<init> The HTTP BIO connector has been removed in Tomcat 8.5.x onwards. The HTTP BIO connector configuration has been automatically switched to use the HTTP NIO connector instead.
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.922 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.923 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.923 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.923 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.923 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ajdk_2\conf\logging.properties
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.923 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59454,suspend=y,server=n
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\Users\admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/capture1471.props
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ajdk_2
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\develop\apache-tomcat-8.5.29
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.924 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\develop\apache-tomcat-8.5.29\temp
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.925 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.925 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
11-Sep-2018 22:42:56.925 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:57.966 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.058 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.068 信息 [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.074 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-443"]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.284 信息 [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.285 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.286 信息 [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.286 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1701 ms
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.306 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.306 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.313 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.320 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-443"]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.322 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
11-Sep-2018 22:42:58.330 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 43 ms
Connected to server
[2018-09-11 10:42:58,701] Artifact ajdk:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
11-Sep-2018 22:43:06.418 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
221
2109226
217
216338
219
831613
7081
11-Sep-2018 22:43:50.921 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
11-Sep-2018 22:43:50.922 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
11-Sep-2018 22:44:09.919 警告 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2018-09-11 10:44:09,937] Artifact ajdk:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
11-Sep-2018 22:44:14.909 信息 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$3]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$3]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1299)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.closeIdle(AbstractConnPool.java:541)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:188)

11-Sep-2018 22:46:17.836 信息 [pool-2-MeetingPhoneIdService-flushThread--1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.saasbee.webapp.util.UUID]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.saasbee.webapp.util.UUID]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1299)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at com.saasbee.webapp.service.meetingphoneid.MeetingPhoneIdService$1.run(MeetingPhoneIdService.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: "One or more listeners failed to start." says that your problem may have a cause we could see in the previous lines of the log you are showing us.

Comment: The log is above.Thanks.

Comment: Above again, please. Until you find another error (= 信息 ?) log message.
There sould be a first cause that made the listener failling to start. If you can't find another one log entry about an error, check on the other logs files you have : the message that appears "One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file" seems to say that informations about your error could have been stored elsewhere.

Comment: I fixed it by changing mysql from version 8.0 to version 5.7.Thank you all the time!